# error while installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following is the error I got when I am installing rails on my linux system, any one's help..most welcome!

```
Installing gem rails-3.2.12
Successfully installed rails-3.2.12
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.12...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `map' for Gem::Specification:Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your ruby gems..

Or you can use

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm install 1.9.3-p194
rvm use 1.9.3
```

One of the good blog for installing rails on linux machine : [RailsInstallationOnRubyMachine](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/)

I hope this may help you in your installation.

Comment: Thanx! When I am typing the commands specified by you it is reacting like this,root@imobigeeks1-desktop:~# rvm reload
bash: /usr/bin/rvm: No such file or directory

Comment: Please go through that blog, definitely you will find the way ...:)